# How to document a 'whatsnew`-rst bugfix before I submit a pandas pull request

Tags: pandas, github

I fixed a minor bug in Pandas.

I followed the instructions in the [pandas contribution guidelines](https://dev.pandas.io/development/contributing.html).  I created a new environment,  built the pandas source, fixed the bug,  ran the testsuite.

All is ready except for the section '[Documenting your code](https://dev.pandas.io/development/contributing.html#documenting-your-code)'
It advises:

> Changes should be reflected in the release notes located in
>   doc/source/whatsnew/vx.y.z.rst. This file contains an ongoing change
>   log for each release. Add an entry to this file to document your fix,
>   enhancement or (unavoidable) breaking change. Make sure to include the
>   GitHub issue number when adding your entry (using :issue:`1234` where
>   1234 is the issue/pull request number).

When I look at my `\whatsnew` directory, I have lots of `.rst` files.  I'm not sure which one to update

```
Directory of C:\Users\foo\code\pfix\pandas-bar\doc\source\whatsnew

25-Jun-19  10:16 PM    <DIR>          .
25-Jun-19  10:16 PM    <DIR>          ..
25-Jun-19  10:16 PM             2,184 index.rst
25-Jun-19  10:16 PM            16,927 v0.10.0.rst
...<clipped for brevity>...
25-Jun-19  10:16 PM           116,771 v0.24.0.rst
25-Jun-19  10:16 PM             3,976 v0.24.1.rst
25-Jun-19  10:16 PM             5,443 v0.24.2.rst
25-Jun-19  10:16 PM            45,462 v0.25.0.rst
25-Jun-19  10:16 PM             3,421 v0.4.x.rst
...<clipped for brevity>...
25-Jun-19  10:16 PM             3,697 v0.9.0.rst
25-Jun-19  10:16 PM             4,973 v0.9.1.rst
25-Jun-19  10:16 PM            20,421 whatsnew_0171_html_table.html
              50 File(s)      1,093,274 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  738,033,799,168 bytes free
```

The output of my environment's `pd.__version__`  is `0.25.0.dev0+791.gf0919f272.dirty`     My guess is that I should update  `v0.25.0.rst` file,  but I'm not certain.   Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing for version `vx.y.z`, then you will be logging your changes in the `vx.y.z.rst` file. In your case, [0.25.0.rst](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/doc/source/whatsnew/v0.25.0.rst).

Your pandas version also reflects this (`vx.y.z.dev[...]`).